# Firebase Auth, java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getDisplayName()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello im coding an app and i use firebase to get the display name of the user after logging in however i get this error only on api 27 `java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getDisplayName()' on a null object reference`

the user is logged in when this happens

my code is

```
String displayname =  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName().toString();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Logged in as "+ displayname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: share log cat here

Answer (score 0):

[FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getCurrentUser()) returns a null FirebaseUser when there is no user logged in.  You're calling `getDisplayName()` on that null reference, which is causing the error.  You should check for null there to see if it's safe to call methods on the User object.

Comment: Absolutely DON'T check for null if it's *not supposed to be* null. And after logging in it's not supposed to be null. That leads me to believe the login flow failed. There's not enough information in the question to debug that.

Comment: this is the first bit of code        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        //checks if a user has logged in
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {

           loginstart();
        }
        else
        {
            onlogin();
        }

Comment: @EugenPechanec That's valid if the code is sitting inside an auth listener, but the code here doesn't give that context.  There are times when you arbitrarily need to know if a user is logged in and change course based on that.  The javadoc I linked to even says to check for null.

Comment: @DougStevenson "i use firebase to get the display name of the user **after logging in**" was the context of my comment. What you listed are of course all valid cases.

Comment: @EugenPechanec The word "after" is ambiguous here. Only the code can reveal what's actually happening here.  They may very well be doing async programming incorrectly.